# how to detect if the app is coming from the background in flutter?

Tags: flutter

how to detect if the app is coming from the background? In android, it directly comes to a resumed state after a pause. But in ios, it behaves like inactive and then resumed after a pause. This coz problem in the case of the system pop up like notification permission when the app goes to inactive and after closing, notification permission pop it goes to direct resume case.

Apps goes to background

1> inactive

2> Pause

Apps come in the foreground after background,

android

3> resume

iOS

3> inactive

4> resume

---

This get mixed when some permission pop comes

Android / iOS

1> Inactive

When we dismiss permission pop up

2> resume

So I can't determine with only the resume state that the app is coming actually from the background.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) and `didChangeAppLifecycleState`, which is called when the system puts the app in the background or returns the app to the foreground.

Comment: I am using same. updated my question check